# Matlab - computing the probability of each element within a vector

Tags: matlab

I am having a vector `y` which may have the following form:

`y = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 4 5]`

And I want to attach a probability to each element within `y` as it would've been generated by a random variable. In this case, the element 1 would have the probability 6/14, the element 2 would have the probability 4/14, the element 3 the value 2/14 and the elements 4 and 5 the value 1/14.

And basically, the result should look like:

`prob_y = 1/14 * [6 6 6 6 4 4 4 4 6 6 2 2 1 1]`

Is there a way of doing this without any `for` or `while` loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unique elements in your input vector can be determined using the [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) function. You can then get the desired output using [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) and an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) that checks the number of each unique element in your input vector:

```
>> y = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 4 5];
>> prob_y = arrayfun(@(x)length(find(y==x)), unique(y)) / length(y)

prob_y =

    0.4286    0.2857    0.1429    0.0714    0.0714
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a histogram with as many bins as the difference between your min & max element (plus one to get total range), then normalize by dividing by the number of elements in you original vector.

Something like this:

```
y = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 4 5]
p = hist(y, max(y) - min(y) + 1) / length(y)
```

**[Edit]** To answer your updated question: use `y` to select the indices from `p`, like this:

```
prob_y = p(y)
```

Comment: And how should I proceed in the situation when I have value like `3.2` in the `y` vector?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html):

```
y = [1.3 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 4 5];

[g,~,gl] = grp2idx(y);
count = accumarray(g,1);
p = count(g) ./ numel(g)
```

The probabilities:

```
>> [y(:) p]
ans =
          1.3     0.071429
            1      0.35714
            1      0.35714
            1      0.35714
            2      0.28571
            2      0.28571
            2      0.28571
            2      0.28571
            1      0.35714
            1      0.35714
            3      0.14286
            3      0.14286
            4     0.071429
            5     0.071429
```

You can see a summary of occurrences as:

```
>> [gl count]
ans =
            1            5
          1.3            1
            2            4
            3            2
            4            1
            5            1
```

Note that I am using [GRP2IDX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/grp2idx.html) to handle cases like `1.3` or integers not starting at `1`.