# Frequency of elements in matrix - Matlab

Tags: matlab, frequency, frequency-distribution

From a function that i run in matlab i get a 225x400 matrix. I want to count the frequency of each element in this matrix, meaning that i need to calculate how many times each elements appears on the the matrix. My matrix name is "Idiff"

I am using:

```
B=unique(Idiff);
```

to find the unique elements in the Idiff matrix. I receive a column of 1138 elements, so i understand that these elements are unique and all the other elements in the Idiff matrix are these elements repeated.

Now i try to count how many times each unique element appears in my Idiff matrix by using:

```
C=histc(Idiff,B);
```

But what i get is a column of 47761 elements and i get confused.

Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [find count of elements in a matrix of two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139447/find-count-of-elements-in-a-matrix-of-two-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
C=histc(Idiff(:),B);
```

Otherwise histc runs on each column separately.

Comment: Great that worked! Now if i want to create the probability of each unique element meaning that i have to calculate this probability of each element=number of occurances/total occurances how can i make this in matlab?