# From data to probability mass function - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there a Matlab function which builds up the exact probability mass function (or probability density function) given a vector of data?

I mean something like this:

```
X = [1 2 4 1 4 3 2 3 4 1];
[x px] = a_function(X)
x = 
   1 2 3 4
px = 
   0.3 0.2 0.2 0.3
```

Comment: this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226474/frequency-of-elements-in-matrix-matlab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)

```
pmf = accumarray(X(:),1)./numel(X);
pmf = pmf./sum(pmf);
```

or [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html):

```
pmf = hist(X, max(X))' ./ numel(X);
```

or [`tabulate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html) :

```
t= tabulate(X);
pmf  = t(:, 3) ./ 100 ;
```

and there's probably at least 10 more ways doing so...

for `px` just use `px=unique(X)`, or `t(:, 1)` in the `tabulate` solution, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that I use (comments `%` replaced with `#` as StackOverflow doesn't parse Matlab correctly).

This could be neatened up (and probably speeded up) using either `accumarray` or `hist` as in [natan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703303/546084).

```
function [vals freqs] = pmf(X)
#PMF Return the probability mass function for a vector/matrix.
#
#INPUTS:
#   X       Input matrix
#
#OUTPUTS:
#   VALS    Vector of unique values
#   FREQS   Vector of frequencies of occurence of each value.
#

    [vals junk idx] = unique(X);

    vals   = vals(:);
    frequs = NaN(length(vals),1);

    for i = 1:length(vals)
        freqs(i) = mean(idx == i);
    end

    # If 0 or 1 output is requested, put the values and counts in two columns
    # of a matrix.
    if nargout < 2
        vals = [vals freqs];
    end

end
```