# Plot the PMF given the realizations of a certain random variable on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, chi-squared, probability-distribution

I have an array with a certain number of realizations of a test.

I need to plot the PMF given my realizations

I've read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703240/from-data-to-probability-mass-function-matlab) but I think in my case, to build the PMF I first need to find the frequency so the values ​​fall within a certain range (like [-1,0],[0,1], etc) but I can't figure out how to do it in a fast way.

Comment: I could have found the solution which is `histogram(X,'Normalization','pdf')` but not sure yet

Comment: You may wan to provide a [minimum valuable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). *chi-square* is a probabilistic test and has nothing to do with random variables

Comment: Yeah sorry, I may have used the wrong words but, I've found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the solution was to use the command

```
histogram(X,'Normalization','pdf')
```

which plot what I was looking for; X is my column vectors containing the realizations