# Get average y value per x position in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I don't know how to phrase this, but an example:

```
x = [1 4 4 5 5 5];
y = [5 1 3 3 4 5];
```

and then I'd like output

```
xs          = [1 4 5];
ys          = [5 2 4];
frequencies = [1 2 3]
```

(because the average 'y' at x=1 is `5`, and the average 'y' at x=4 is `(1+3)/2 = 2`, and the average 'y' at x=5 is `(3+4+5)/3 = 4`).

I can compute this in a clumsy way but maybe there's a nice solution.

Comment: Don't have time to try it now, but perhaps the second answer to this question can be a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880933/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-elements-of-a-given-value-in-a-matrix   As you probably know the clumsy but simple way to do this would be to loop over `unique(x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the histogramming function `histc` to get each of the categories:

```
x = [ 1 4 4 5 5 5];
y = [ 5 1 3 3 4 5];
xs = unique(x);
[frequencies xb] = histc(x, xs); % counts the number of each unique occurrence
ysp = sparse(1:numel(x), xb, y); % a sparse matrix is a good way to organize the numbers
ys = full(sum(ysp)./sum(ysp>0)); % each column in the matrix corresponds to a "index"
```

This gives you the three arrays you wanted. I think this is quite clean and efficient - no looping, only four lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = [1 4 4 5 5 5];
y = [5 1 3 3 4 5];
xs = unique(x);
[frequencies,bin] = histc(x,xs);
ys = arrayfun(@(i) mean(y(bin==i)), 1:length(xs));
```

Comment: +1: expression for `xs` can also be estimated by a running index for example `ys = arrayfun(@(k) mean(y(x==xs(k))), 1:length(xs));`

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: `arrayfun` may be neat, but it is usually slower than a loop.

Answer (score 2):

@ioum 's answer worked great for me, there was a small mistake though in the last line, that came up when I gave as an input other vectors than the ones posted here. For example, after deleting the last element of each vector the answer should be:

```
ys = [5 2 3.5]
```

The slightly corrected code is:

```
x = [1 4 4 5 5 5];
y = [5 1 3 3 4 5];
xs = unique(x);
[frequencies,bin] = histc(x,xs);
ys = arrayfun(@(i) mean(y(bin==i)), 1:length(xs));
```

I tried to edit @ioum 's post, but the edit did not go through.

Comment: You are correct. I'm not sure why your edit would be rejected, but I have now made the edit myself.

Comment: Awesome, thanks (for both correcting and for saving me a lot of time in the first place)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solution would be considered elegant enough, but this should work:

```
x = [1 4 4 5 5 5];
y = [5 1 3 3 4 5];
[xs,I,J] = unique(x);    %The value of the index vector I is not required here.
ys = zeros(size(xs));
frequencies = zeros(size(xs));
for i = 1:max(J)
    I = find(J==i);
    ys(i) = mean(y(I));
    frequencies(i) = length(I);
end
xs,ys,frequencies
```

The output would be:

```
xs =

     1     4     5


ys =

     5     2     4


frequencies =

     1     2     3
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Try not to use I or J as variables

Comment: @user1134241: Sorry, but why? Is that a problem?

Comment: This is exactly as I did it but didn't find it really elegant :)

Comment: @FrankMeulenaar: I wasn't sure it would be. :) At least the answer rustled up some activity on the question. :D

Anyway, I hope you found what you were looking for in some other answer here.

Comment: The problem with using `i` and `j` is that they are `sqrt(-1)` until you overwrite them. Other code that expects them to have their built in value will subsequently fail. They are 'not quite reserved" names...  Matlab is full of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1 4 4 5 5 5]';
y = [5 1 3 3 4 5]';
```

%this can probably be done smarter...

```
indexlong=accumarray(x,x,[],@mean)'
meanlong=accumarray(x,y,[],@mean)'
frequencieslong=accumarray(x,1)'
```

%leave out zeros

```
takethese=(indexlong>0);
xs=indexlong(takethese)
ys=meanlong(takethese)
frequencies=frequencieslong(takethese)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my code, hope it helps...

```
   x=sort(x);
   ind=1;
    for i=1:length(x)
        if (i>1 && x(i)==x(i-1))
           continue;
        end
        xs(ind)=x(i);
        freq(ind)=sum((x==x(i)));
        ys(ind)=sum((x==x(i)).*y)/freq(ind);
        ind=ind+1;
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I would recommend one of the histogram approaches, here is how I would do it in a loop. Not that much different from some other solutions but I believe it is just a little nicer so I will post it anyway.

```
xs = unique(x)
for t = 1:length(xs)
   idx = x == xs(t);
   ys(t) = mean(y(idx));
   frequencies(t) = sum(idx);
end
```