# Counting no of repeating elements in an array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

suppose i have an array (in matlab) like this :

A = [ 1 1 1 3 6 2 2 2 3 4 3 3];

i want another array suppose X to be an array containing those elements of A that are more than 3 in count e.g. X should be [1 2 3]

is there a function that can do this for me? if so what is it?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880933/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-elements-of-a-given-value-in-a-matrix for a number of techniques to count elements in a matrix. It's trivial to extend the given solutions so that you get a report of those elements occuring at least three times.

Answer (score 3):

This will do it using [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
A = [1 1 1 3 6 2 2 2 3 4 3 3];
u = unique(A);
X = u(histc(A,u)>=3)
```

which returns

```
X =

   1     2     3
```