# how ca I use from duplicate entries as condition?

Tags: matlab, duplicates

Given a vector

```
a=[
     1
     2
     3
     9
    12
    13
    14
    17
     8
     9
    12
    13
    14
    17];
```

how can we sure that an element is duplicate and use this as a condition. I want say if a have a duplicate number so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine if there is any duplicate:

```
result = sum(sum(bsxfun(@eq, a, a.'))) > numel(a);
```

This gives `true` if there any duplicates and `false` otherwise.

---

Or:

```
result = numel(unique(a)) < numel(a);
```

---

Or:

```
result = any(diff(sort(a))==0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the counts for each element

```
C = accumarray(M, 1);
counts = C(a);
```

**Note:** you can also use any of the other methods outlines in the reference below to get the number of counts.

Then flag which elements have more than 1 count

```
dups = counts > 1;
```

**References**

[How can I count the number of elements of a given value in a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880933/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-elements-of-a-given-value-in-a-matrix)